# Authorization failure while issuing identity hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I read the answer suggesting to check the docker.yaml for ca.

The file path is below where I confirm that the username is admin and password is adminpw. Unfortunately I still get authorizatin failure error.

command I use to issue identity

```
composer identity issue -n 'trade-network' -p hlfv1 -i admin -s adminpw -u trader1 -a "org.acme.trading.Trader#TRADER1"
```

Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]]
Command failed.

/home/composer/fabric-tools/fabric-scripts/hlfv1/composer/docker-compose.yml
line from docker.yaml

```
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/a22daf356b2aab5792ea53e35f66fccef1d7f1aa2b3a2b92dbfbf96a448ea26a_sk -b admin:adminpw -d'
```

Comment: So your command sequence and password (for a default dev HLF V1 setup) is correct. It sounds like your CA server docker container has certificates that don't match what's in your .composer-credentials vault ($HOME/.,composer-credentials vault (eg. docker container was recreated etc). If so - if you  check the contents (in the directory above) of the 'admin' file  -using `cat admin` you'll see the "signingIdentity" value (~64 chars) matches that of the filenames in that directory, suffixed "-pub" and "-priv". Remove these two files and the admin file (outdated) and try to issue the id again.

Comment: thnks for the reply. I done two things first I remove  .composer-credentials directory and run creteProfile.sh again. secondly I reailze that there are still beta images of hyperledger fabric and removed them all. currently I am fine :)

Comment: I now have the same problem since the switch to _business network cards_. On a newly started network the admin can add participants, but not issue identities. Even after a full `./teardownFabric.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the old admin credentails under ($HOME/.composer-credential), and go back to the existing business network and run either bash for adding identity or through composer-rest-server -p xxxx -n xxxx -i admin -s adminspw to call the endpoint for issuing new identity

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar error where I was able to add participants using playground however while issuing identity I face this error of Authorisation.

Workaround:

Delete the admin card :

```
composer card delete --card admin@your-network-name
```

Import the card :

```
composer card import -f admin@your-network-name
```

again install and start the network using below command.

install :

```
composer network install -a your-network-name@0.0.1.bna -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1
```

start :

```
composer network start -c PeerAdmin@hlfv1 -V 0.0.1 -n your-network-name -A admin -S adminpw
```

then Import the card and try issuing identity you will not see the error.

Answer (score 0):

this problem cause can be your username & pwd for CA container

double check your docker container config, find someplace that looks like

```
/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/CA1_PRIVATE_KEY -b admin:adminpw -d'
```

make sure that your configured username&pwd same with username&pwd in your command