# composer identity issue Authorization failure error hyperldeger composer v0.15.0

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I had the same issue which discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231724/authorization-failure-while-issuing-identity-hyperldeger-composer), and based on comments I fixed the problem by removing .composer-credentials directory and deploying my network again. Now I am using the new version of composer(v0.15.0). I already removed two directories (`.composer-credentials` and `.composer-connection-profiles`), but again when I run

`composer identity issue -c admin@test-network -f membercard -u member -a "resource:org..."`

I get the same error --> fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[{"code":400,"message":"Authorization failure"}]].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 0.15.x release connection profiles are not stored in ${HOME}/.composer-connection-profiles anymore. They are stored in your cards. Connection profiles should now not include a keyValStore property and as such the directory ${HOME}/.composer-credentials is not used to cache credentials anymore.
For 0.15.0 if you want to clear out cards and cached credentials then for now you need to delete the ${HOME}/.composer directory and re-import all your cards.
In the future you will be able to delete a card which will also clear any cached credentials.

Comment: That was helpful. I removed ~/.composer directory and fabric-scripts and start again, so the problem fixed. With the older version when I issued a new identity it gave me a secret which I can connect to the system with it. I am interested to know how the new version works without the secret.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a full history of what you have done but the following sequence should help.

With v0.15.0 we have moved to the business network cards, and you are using them on your command line with the -c option.
Having deleted the `~/.composer-credentials` and `~/.composer-connection-profiles` folders associated with older versions I assume that you also created the PeerAdmin card using the  `createPeerAdminCard.sh` script from fabric tools.

I assume that you have executed the 2 commands:
`composer runtime install ...` and
`composer network start ...`

and then run:
`composer card import ...` to import the card of the Network Admin that you created with the `composer network start` command.

To diagnose you problem further I would sugggest:
`composer card list`
and
`composer card list --name` 
to confirm the cards you have

Then ping to confirm your Network Admin works OK
`composer network ping...`

Now try 
`composer network list ...`
The list which will show you the participants you have (amongst other things) and the participants should match up with the data you are passing with -a in the composer identity issue command.

At this point you should have seen if the Network Admin ID that was originally causing the access problem works OK, or should have more information to follow up with.

Answer (score 0):

Since I am using v0.15.0 ,I faced the same issue for issuing identities for newly created participants. After removing the `${HOME}/.composer`, `${HOME}/.composer-credentials` and `${HOME}/.composer-connection-profiles` directory and reimporting the cards solved my issue.